# How to apply "Sum(vi * ln(vi))" on each row of an RDD "org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector)]"

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have an RDD with this structure

```
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector)]
```

Here each row of RDD contains an index `Long` and a vector `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector`. I want to apply the following function to each vector, present in each row.

**Function is: Sum(vi * ln(vi)), where vi = ith component of a vector.**

Please guide me how can I apply this function to an RDD with a structure mentioned above in scala.

An example row would look like this:

```
Array[(Long, org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector)] = 
      Array((0,[0.024866109194373365,0.025451635045582396,0.024940244042347803,
                0.025318245591768037,0.026531498776299952,0.02335951025503321,
                0.02388238099930112,0.023397342214386187,0.024965559145567116,
                0.023650490684903713,0.023343404489401316,0.024368157919182634,
                0.02526665811061871,0.025846888476461573,0.025874255477319974))
```

Comment: please share an example dataset.

Comment: @mtoto thank you for your response, here is an example `Array[(Long, org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector)] = Array((0,[0.024866109194373365,0.025451635045582396,0.024940244042347803,0.025318245591768037,0.026531498776299952,0.02335951025503321,0.02388238099930112,...`

Comment: by `ln()` you mean logarithm ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try converting your `Vector` column into type `Array`, so way we can map `x * log(x)` to each element, and finally `sum` the resulting `Array` with a second `mapValues` call:

```
rdd.mapValues(_.toArray.map(x => scala.math.log(x) * x)).mapValues(_.sum)
```